# How to open slider popup from grid widget form using action column

Tags: grid, adminform, magento2.4.5, modal-popup

I have loaded the widget block form grid in the edit product section.

I am trying to open the model popup in the adminhtml widget grid form.

I have added the action column like below

```
$this->addColumn('action', array(
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'width' => '50',
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getProductId',
                'actions' => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => __('Add Content'),
                        'url' => array('base' => 'catalog/product/edit'),
                        'target'=>'_blank',
                        'field' => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                
        ));
```

Action column added in my grid but now I want to open the slider model popup or normal model popup with form on click of add content link,

I also tried to load with the renderer method but unable to load it.

Could anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a modal popup with a form when clicking on the "Add Content" link in the action column of your widget grid, you'll need to make a few modifications.

First, update the 'actions' array in your column definition to include a 'popup' key with the value set to true. This will ensure that the link opens in a modal popup:

```
'actions' => array(
    array(
        'caption' => __('Add Content'),
        'url' => array('base' => 'catalog/product/edit'),
        'target' => '_blank',
        'field' => 'id',
        'popup' => true // Open in a modal popup
    )
),
```

Next, you'll need to define a renderer for the action column to handle the opening of the modal. You can do this by adding a 'renderer' key with a value representing the class that will render the column content:

```
'renderer' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Action',
```

In the specified renderer class, you can implement the logic to display the link and handle the opening of the modal. Here's an example implementation:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Action as BaseAction;

class Action extends BaseAction
{
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $productId = $row->getProductId();
        $url = $this->getUrl('catalog/product/edit', ['id' => $productId]);
        $this->getColumn()->setActions([
            [
                'caption' => __('Add Content'),
                'url' => $url,
                'field' => 'id',
                'popup' => true // Open in a modal popup
            ]
        ]);
        
        return parent::render($row);
    }
}
```

In this renderer class, the render() method is overridden to modify the action link and set the 'popup' key to true. This ensures that the link opens in a modal popup. Finally, the modified actions array is set back to the column before rendering it using the parent renderer.

Make sure to replace 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Action' with the actual class path of your renderer class.

By following these steps, the "Add Content" link in the action column should open the desired model popup with a form.

Comment: Hi @Noor Mohamed, Thanks Man now popup is appeared :) You save my days.

Also you explained very well :)

I have couple of questions, 
1. can we open the popup like Advance inventory?
2. how to load custom form inside that popup

Comment: As I tried to pass through controller to open custom form but the form is not loaded with button data